# MySQL multiple outputs from single query statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to output two value from a same query like

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `find`(IN A varchar(100), OUT B varchar(100), OUT C varchar(100))
BEGIN

Select b_col into B, c_col into C from table where a_col = A

END
```

It seems like it is not possible to using "into" twice. is it needed to make a temp table for the output?

What would be the best solution to achieve this, welcome for any suggestion

Thanks you

Comment: If any of the answer solved your problem (and both should have) you might want to mark one as accepted, and or upvote if appropriate. (I just wrote this as I noticed that you haven't accepted any answer so far and might not be aware of the possibility to do so).

Answer (score 0):

You just list the variables in the `into` clause:

```
Select b_col into B, c_col into B, C
from table
where a_col = A;
```

I would suggest that you prefix your parameter variables to distinguish them from columns.  Perhaps `in_A`, `out_B`, and `out_C`.

Comment: I think the first `into` is a typo and isn't meant to be there?

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me right all target variables should be listed after the `into` keyword, like this:

```
Select b_col, c_col into B,C from table where a_col = A
```